# Php script that download file not work under ubuntu 14

Tags: php, ubuntu, download, xampp

I've a file named **openFile.php** with this data inside:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['pathFile'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Ecoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file).'');
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
else
{
   echo("<h1 style='text-align:center;color:red;font-size:bold;'>File ".basename($file)." non trovato !</h1>");
}
?>
```

I use this script everyday under Windows with XAMPP and all works correctly, but i have change my server with Ubuntu 14.04 and now when I try to download somethink the browser download a file without extension and without content.

Comment: This might be a permission issue. Can you check the permissions that you have given to this file in ubuntu? You can use command: chmod to change permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is persmission issue then give permission :

> sudo chmod -R 777 [file path]

**Note** : check log file to see error message

```
tail -20 /var/log/apache2/error.log
tail -20 /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: I try to execute this command....now if i upload and download a png file its works but if i upload and try to download another type ex.pdf not work.